# Dereferencing a casted void pointer and using post increment operator

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have a function

```
foo(void *buf) {
int i = 0;
unsigned char ptr = get_user_name();
//I want the buffer to hold user name from some position onwards
   for(i=0;i<MESSAGE_LTH;i++) 
  *( (unsigned char*)(buf) + sizeof(some_struct)) ++ = ptr[i];
}
```

I am getting  `error: lvalue required as increment operand`
I want the buffer to hold the username soon after the struct;

Comment: What did you _intend_ to do?

Comment: @timrau the buffer first few bytes will hold (some_struct) of data and the type of struct changes, so I want the username to come soon after the struct in buffer.

Comment: Do y ou understand why `n++ = 10;` doesn't work?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes I do understand that! I am unable to form the syntax properly for my requirement.

Comment: @kartik: No, this isn't about syntax. It's about the semantics of post-increment and lvalues. Which is why I gave a simpler version of the problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes I get it.

Comment: OK. Seems like this problem isn't too hard; why do you insist on using `++`? Just write obvious, loop free code?

Comment: @KerrekSB the use of ++ is so that the buffer will point to the next location automatically after the username is inserted and at that position I can start filling other fields.

Comment: @kartik: You can do that in a single operation. No need for `++`. And you cannot perform arithmetic on `buf` directly, since that's a void pointer. You need to keep a local char pointer around on which you perform arithmetic. Currently you do that on the temporary value created by the cast.

Comment: @KerrekSB  just to quench my curiosity how to do it

Comment: The way you were using `++` was not to increment the pointer but an attempt to both increment the pointer's target *and also* set it to ptr[i]. Also you can't use `++` to increment an intermediate calculation value such as `(a+b)++`, it has to be a specific variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line should be rewritten as

```
*( (unsigned char*)(buf) + sizeof(some_struct) + i) = ptr[i];
```

Indeed, an easier-to-understand implementation:

```
memcpy(buf + sizeof(some_struct), ptr, MESSAGE_LTH);
```

without the loop.

Comment: Thanks but I want the buffer to point to the next location immediately after the username is attached so that I can attach more fields to it.

Comment: Increase the pointer after the copy is ready. Keep the code straightforward makes life easier.

Comment: Just out of curiosity , how to use ++ operator for getting the same result?

Comment: `*( (unsigned char*)(buf++) + sizeof(some_struct)) = ptr[i];`

Comment: can I some avoid using 'i' on the LHS?

Comment: The `memcpy` version has no `i` in LHS.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
unsigned char ptr = get_user_name();
```

seems like it should be:

```
const unsigned char *ptr = get_user_name();
```

It must be a pointer since you're accessing it like one. It should be `const` since you're only reading from it.

The copying should be done using `memcpy()`, and incrementing the pointer afterwards can be done separately:

```
unsigned char *put = buf;      /* Proper type, for pointer arithmetic. */
put += sizeof(some_struct);    /* Advance into the buffer. */
memcpy(put, ptr, MESSAGE_LTH); /* Do the copy. */
put += MESSAGE_LTH;            /* Advance the pointer to after the name. */
```

Of course at the end of the above, it's hard to know what to do with `put`. Perhaps returning it out of the function would make sense, but you don't specify.